# Converting a exponential a string

Tags: r, string, type-conversion

I am trying to assign names in a new column based on the values of an adjacent column. 
 I am using a function which takes a pattern and replaces it with another:

```
sub<-function(pattern, replacement, x, ...) {
   result <- x
   for (i in 1:length(pattern)) {
   result <- gsub(pattern[i], replacement[i], result, ...)
    }
   result
 }
```

I can take the following:

```
df$x<-as.character(df$x)

df$y<-(sub(c("1A1","1B2", "1.00E+01"),
           c("P1", "P2", "P3"), df$x))
```

So, df$y will now contain P1, P2 where 1A1, 1B2 are present in df$x. However, "1.00E+02" does not give P3 in df$y, 1.00E+02 is copied to it.

Am I missing something about exponents and how they are read as patterns?

Here is an example of my data table where df$x is ID and df$y is Name:

```
 Name       ID
 p1         1A1
 p2         1B2
 1.00E+01   1.00E+01
```

Any help would be appreciated.
 Thanks MF

Comment: Read the documentation. If you pass a vector of length > 1 as `pattern`, only its first element is used. Also, by default the pattern is understood as a regular expression.

Comment: Sorry if I'm wrong but if pattern was only recognising the first element used then there would be no distinguishing between 1A1 and 1B2, however there is. It is only the 1.00E+01 which causes the issue.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. If I try it only the first element is changed.

Comment: That is strange. If I copy and run the function sub from here, the string is used not the first element.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't see that you defined a function `sub`. That's a bad idea, because there is a (closely related) base function `sub`.

Answer (score 1):

The `pattern` is parsed as a regular expression by default and `.` and `+` have a special meaning in regex. Use `fixed = TRUE`:

```
mysub<-function(pattern, replacement, x, ...) {
  result <- x
  for (i in 1:length(pattern)) {
    result <- gsub(pattern[i], replacement[i], result, fixed = TRUE, ...)
  }
  result
}

x <- c("1A1", "1B2", "1.00E+01")
mysub(c("1A1","1B2", "1.00E+01"),
     c("P1", "P2", "P3"), x)
#[1] "P1" "P2" "P3"
```

I prefer using `factor` for this:

```
as.character(factor(x, 
                    levels = c("1A1","1B2", "1.00E+01"), 
                    labels = c("P1", "P2", "P3")))
#[1] "P1" "P2" "P3"
```

Comment: Hi Roland, yep it was definitely the + symbol which messed up 1.00E+0X values. If it is of any interest I found the following work around.

  '  mysub2 <-function(pattern, replacement, x, ...) {
     result <- rep("", length(x))
      for (i in 1:length(pattern)){
       result[x==pattern[i]]<-replacement[i]
     }
      result
    }'

Answer (score 0):

@Roland, yep it was definitely the + symbol which messed up 1.00E+0X values. If it is of any interest I found the following work around.

```
 mysub2 <-function(pattern, replacement, x, ...) {
     result <- rep("", length(x))
      for (i in 1:length(pattern)){
       result[x==pattern[i]]<-replacement[i]
     }
      result
    }
```